# Wrong type inference for TextField `helperText` using Formik and MUI

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui, formik

I've never had an issue with `helperText` on on the `TextField` component before but i've just upgraded to react-scripts 5 and this basically broke a bunch of stuff since my typescript is weak. anyway here's some more information below about what's actually going on.

The error:

```
TS2322: Type 'string | false | string[] | FormikErrors<any> | FormikErrors<any>[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
    313 |                           touched.controlType && errors.controlType,
    314 |                         )}
  > 315 |                         helperText={touched.controlType && errors.controlType}
        |                         ^^^^^^^^^^
    316 |                         label="Control type"
    317 |                         name="controlType"
    318 |                         variant="filled"
```

the code:

```
<Autocomplete
  disableClearable={false}
  disableCloseOnSelect={false}
  onBlur={handleBlur}
  onChange={(_, value) => setFieldValue('controlType', value)}
  options={CONTROL_TYPES || []}
  filterSelectedOptions
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      error={Boolean(
        touched.controlType && errors.controlType,
      )}
      helperText={touched.controlType && errors.controlType}
      label="Control type"
      name="controlType"
      variant="filled"
      {...params}
    />
  )}
  value={values.controlType}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue and it turns out in this case it is better to check the type of errors content manually. The solution is actually documented [here](https://formik.org/docs/api/fieldarray#fieldarray-validation-gotchas).

The following solved it for me:

```js
      helperText={(touched.controlType && errors.controlType && typeof errors.controlType === 'string') && errors.controlType}"
      {...params}
```

You may also get rid of the first 'errors.controlType' but I believe it is safer to check for null values first.

Comment: Thanks for the follow up. I'll revisit this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem for this is with your Type Annotations. You should ideally set them correctly. I suspect that type for controlType is either set to `any` or not properly set. I ran into similar situation with `any` (see example below)

```
const controlType: any = your data
```

but if you set to

```
const controlType: IControlType = your data
```

the error is likely to go away.

```
<Formik
    initialValues={controlType}
```

assuming you have only one Component.

Although the solution suggested above works, i feel it is not correct way to fix.

```
helperText={(touched.controlType && errors.controlType && typeof errors.controlType === 'string') && errors.controlType}"
      {...params}
```